# Unable to start Genymotion virtual device,Video cart support OpenGL

Tags: android, genymotion

I am starting virtual device then it's display for few second after that generate below error[image]

Comment: the dialog shows no explanation needed. just update your card drivers.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to run it on a Virtual Machine? Because it's not possible...